# DataGrid - Cell StyleSelector

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, selector

I want to use my StyleSelector for each cell in DataGrid.
But when I do this:

```
ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource cellStyleSelector}"
```

I set StyleSelector of DataGridRow.
How can I add StyleSelector to DataGridCell?